# How historically correct is the Maharana Pratap serial?

Tags: india

My family follows the [Maharana Pratap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharat_Ka_Veer_Putra_%E2%80%93_Maharana_Pratap) serial; I am not sure whether following events are historically correct.

1. Pratap and Akbar meeting when they were young.
2. Rao surtan surfacing multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

It is all fictionalized, just as any other "Historical" serial on Indian television channels. Please ignore or take it as a new story/fanatsy.

As a general rule, each episode in such serials is 23 to 27 minutes long, based merely on "drama"(melodrama?), not on fact. The episodes are built in a manner which is purely sitcom, with no basis on any record, because the drama being portrayed is so "unrecorded". The idea behind such serials is purely entertainment, and all viewers also accept it as such, without any desire for "fact".

There have however, been the occasional protests on legitimacy/accuracy. For example, check the [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/Mahaarana.Pratap.Official.Fanpage) page where there is a comment that it is historically inaccurate, as well as an [online news item](http://www.udaipurtimes.com/rajput-community-objects-to-tv-serial-on-maharana-pratap/) where people are protesting about such inaccuracy.

Comment: Can you provide at least a couple of examples of historical inaccuracies in the serial? We prefer answers that expose facts, not mere opinions.

Comment: @YannisRizos You may check the [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/Mahaarana.Pratap.Official.Fanpage) page where there is a comment that it is historically inaccurate, as well as an online [news item](http://www.udaipurtimes.com/rajput-community-objects-to-tv-serial-on-maharana-pratap/) where people are protesting about such inaccuracy.

Comment: Please update your answer to include all that info (my downvote is now locked and I can't retract it unless you edit the answer).